# Is python's slicing sytax used on model queryset excuted on database level?

Tags: django, django-models

model:

```
class person(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
```

If I use

```
persons = person.objects.order_by('name')[0:25]
```

in the code, is the slice executed on database level (converting to SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY name LIMIT 25) or on the "code" level?

Comment: Side note, don't do [0:25]. [:25] is the exact same thing, but more "Pythony" and saves a character. Which matters to some people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made very clear [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) (and the answer is yes is does):

> Use a subset of Python’s array-slicing syntax to limit your QuerySet to a certain number of results. This is the equivalent of SQL’s LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, slicing gets translated to SQL's `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on when it's executed.

Django's ORM QuerySets are "lazy", in that they don't actually run until they are iterated over. This lets you do things like this:

```
persons = person.objects.filter(age__gte=25)
persons = persons.filter(age__lte=50)
persons = persons.exclude(age=30)
persons = persons.order_by('name')
persons = persons[:25]
for person in persons:
    print person.name
```

Which translates to "Get everyone over the age of 25, under the age of 50, excluding anyone who is 30, order by their name, and give me the first 25 records.

Because the `QuerySet` is lazy, all of that code only creates a single database call, when you actually enter the `for` loop.

So, yes, technically, order_by translates to a LIMIT, when the ORM enters the loop.

However, what the ORM does behind the scenes is a create a Python list of each record the database returns. So, let's say we continue on after the above:

```
for person in persons: # SQL command is compiled and run, with a list returned
    print person.name
persons = persons[:10] # Django just slices the list we already have in memory.
```

It may seem trivial, or an edge case, but it's important to understand what's happening behind the scenes.